# Is BIND DNS + DLZ good for adding subdomain's dynamically?

Tags: dns, bind

Is BIND DNS + [DLZ](http://bind-dlz.sourceforge.net/) reliable? scalable?

Is it a better solution than writing a script and restarting BIND to support adding subdomain's dynamically?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like DLZ is not really needed since BIND has 'Dynamic Update'

reference: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/dns/ch10_02.htm